# JDBC for SQLite in Netbeans: No suitable driver found

Tags: java, sqlite, netbeans, jdbc, sqlexception

I need to load data from an SQLite file into a java program which I develop in Netbeans.
The file is to be loaded via a swing menu item. I'm using [sqlitejdbc](https://bitbucket.org/xerial/sqlite-jdbc/downloads#tag-downloads) as driver.

Here are the code blocks I assume to be important:

```
// header stuff
package aufgabe_9;

import java.sql.*;

//...

// menu item opening the file
private void mitemOpenFileActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)  
{                                              

    /**
     * Handles the dialogue for selecting and loading file.
     */
    JFileChooser fileChoose = new JFileChooser();
    fileChoose.showOpenDialog(this); //'this' calls the current object

     //Load the sql file
     try {
        String filePath = fileChoose.getSelectedFile().toString();
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:" +  
                    filePath);

        //Close the connection
        if (conn != null)
            conn.close();

    }


    catch (SQLException e){System.err.println("Database problem: " + e);}
    }                                  
}

//...
```

When running the program and loading a file via the menu, I get the following error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlite:/home/levent
/temp/A9AProbeflaeche.db
```

After reading the respective stackexchange posts, I understand that this 
problem can be caused by (1) a malformed file URL or (2) the driver not being
loaded. Here's some further information:

- I added the sqlitejdbc-3.7.2.jar to the library classpath via *Tools --> Libraries* as well as to the project libraries via *Window --> Projects*.
- I also checked the *Classpath* by using [this function](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-print-out-the-current-project-classpath/). It contains the path to the jdbc jar-file just as expected.
- I can connect to the database via the *Services* menu without any problems, so I can assume the URL to be correct, as well as sqlite running on my system.
- Some OS information: I'm running Netbeans 8.0 on 64 bit ARCH Linux 3.12.9-2.

Can anybody tell me what I'm missing here? Any help appreciated!

**Problem solved**
Here is the code that works for me:

```
//...
private void mitemOpenFileActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)   
{                                              

    /**
    * Handles the dialogue for selecting and loading file.
    */
    JFileChooser fileChoose = new JFileChooser();
    fileChoose.showOpenDialog(this); 

    //Load the sql file
    try {
        //Get file path
        String filePath = fileChoose.getSelectedFile().toString();

        //Open connection
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:" + filePath);

        //Do stuff...                       

        //Close the connection
        conn.close();

    }

    //"Multicatch":
    catch (SQLException | ClassNotFoundException e) { 
    System.err.println("Database problem: " + e);
}
//...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to load the driver class so that it registers itself to the DriverManager using the following code:
    Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");

Note: this only needs to be called once in your application.

This was a standard procedure before the Java included the ServiceLoader API, now the DriverManager uses that API to register the drivers it finds in the classpath, but the drivers need to declare a file named java.sql.Driver containing the name of the driver class in the directory META-INF\services of their jar.

Comment: Damn straight, thanks a lot! I actually read about the `Class.forName()` statement in different posts, but still got errors at that time, probably because of a malformed url. Also, I assumed it to be obsolete because of the `DriverManager` handling it. It works perfectly now.