# JDBC for SQLite: 'No suitable driver found' although Class.forName works

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc

although I followed the numerous answers/tips on this topic I got stuck.

```
import org.sqlite.JDBC; // no problems during compile
...
class Foo {
    ...
    public Connection connect(String jdbcUrl) {
        try {
            // Class is found -> no exception
            Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC"); 
            // **kaboom**... "No suitable driver found"
            // JDBC-String is 
            //     'jdbc:sqlite:C:/foo/bar/baz.db'
            // Also 
            //     'jdbc:sqlite:memory' 
            // does not work.
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionString);
```

So the class path seems to be ok and the JDBC string is as suggested by tutorials. What do I miss?

Driver (xerial) version is 3.19.3 (tried also 3.15.1).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: And what does your `connectionString` look like?

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24353597/jdbc-for-sqlite-in-netbeans-no-suitable-driver-found?rq=1

Comment: Is an exception thrown ? Could show the stack trace ?

Comment: Your connection URL must be malformed. Please [edit] your question to show us *exactly* what you are trying to use. Also FYI, `jdbc:sqlite:memory` will create a disk-based database named "memory" in the current working directory. If you want an in-memory database you need to use `jdbc:sqlite::memory:`.

Comment: Per the OP's deleted "answer", the actual problem was a typo in the JDBC URL they were using.  (Question should be closed ...)